# VueJS How to use parent method from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

From the component I want to access methods of the parent. 
(Without props)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="el">
    <user v-for="user in users" :item="user"></user>
</div>
```

Here's the Vue code:

```
var usersData = [
    { id:1, firstname:'John', lastname: 'Doe' },
    { id:2, firstname:'Martin', lastname: 'Bust' }
];

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: { users: usersData },
    methods: {
        getFullName: function (user) {
            return user.id + '. ' + user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
        }
    },
    components: {
        user: {
            template: '<span>{{ fullName }}</span>',
            props: ['item'],
            computed: {
                fullName: function(){
                    return this.$parent.getFullName(this.item);
                }
            },
        }
    }
});
```

VueJS version: 2.0.2

Both are `this.$parent.$options.methods.getFullName()` and `this.$parent.methods.getFullName()` not working.

Comment: Just run this code on jsbin and It works - it return full names, as It should.I'm wonder what issue you see ?

Comment: Thank you, it works on jsbin.

Comment: Using `this.$parent` is not recommended though, i don't know it it's alright to access parent function this way without props. Sure it will work, there's nothing wrong with your code snippet.

Comment: The Vue 2.0 documentation suggests using ```inject``` and ```provide``` for a better scaling solution: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Vue.js version 2.2.0+ you can use dependency injection with `inject` and `provide` like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="el">
    <user v-for="user in users" :item="user"></user>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var usersData = [
    { id:1, firstname:'John', lastname: 'Doe' },
    { id:2, firstname:'Martin', lastname: 'Bust' }
];

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: { users: usersData },
    methods: {
        getFullName: function (user) {
            return user.id + '. ' + user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
        }
    },
    provide: function () {
        return {
            getFullName: this.getFullName
        }
    },
    components: {
        user: {
            template: '<span>{{ fullName }}</span>',
            inject: ['getFullName'],
            props: ['item'],
            computed: {
                fullName: function(){
                    return this.getFullName(this.item);
                }
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/haaiee/v1ahoytm/2/